# If $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb R$, there exists a nullset $N$ with $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(x+n)=0 \ \text{ for all } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus N$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue integrable. Show that there exists a nullset $N$, such that
>   $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(x+n)=0 \ \text{ for all } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus N$$

Things I've considered is Fatou to show that the integral over $f$ is $0$ which is equivalent to $f=0$ almost everywhere. However, I somehow can't put things correctly to get the proof.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: We can assume that $f(x)\geq0$ by replacing $f$ by $|f|$ if necessary. Recall that both are Lebesgue integrable simultaneously. We have that $A:=\{x:\liminf_n f(x+n)>0\}=\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}\{x:\ \forall n,\ f(x+n)\geq \frac{1}{m}\}$. Assume that one of the sets $B_m:=\{x:\ \forall n,\ f(x+n)\geq \frac{1}{m}\}$ has positive measure. Then there is some interval $[n_m,n_m+1]$ such that $C_m:=B_m\cap[n_m,n_m+1]$ has positive measure. Then $\int f\geq\int_{B_m}f\geq \int_{C_m}f(x)+\int_{C_m}f(x+1)+...=\infty$. This contradicts that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Therefore the $B_m$ have measure zero, and so do the set $A$. Oh! $A$ should be the $N$ in the statement of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

There are two nice ways to show this (or something very similar)

---

First note that a simple change of variables yields

$$
\int_0^\infty |f(x+n)| \, dx = \int_n^\infty |f(y)| \, dy = \int_\Bbb{R} |f(y)| \chi_{(n,\infty)}(y) \, dy \to 0.
$$

Here the last convergence is justified by dominated convergence, because the integrand converges to $0$ pointwise and is dominated by $|f|$, which is integrable by assumption.

Using Fatou's Lemma, we conclude

$$
0 \leq \int_0^\infty \liminf_n |f(x+n)| \, dx \leq \liminf_n \int_0^\infty |f(x+n)| \, dx = 0.
$$

But a nonnegative function has integral zero iff it vanishes almost everywhere. Hence, we have shown

$$
\liminf_n |f(x+n)| = 0 \text{ for almost all } x > 0.
$$

A similar argument shows the same convergence for almost all $x < 0$.

The only problem here is that this shows the claim for $|f|$ instead of $f$.

---

We can fix this problem using the so-called **periodization trick**. Using monotone convergence and a change of variables, we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\infty > \int_\Bbb{R} |f(x)| \, dx &=& \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{[0,1) + k} |f(x)| \, dx \\ &=& \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{[0,1)} |f(x+k)| \, dx \\ &=&  \int_{[0,1)} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |f(x+k)| \, dx .
\end{eqnarray*}

Since a function with finite integral has to be finite-valued almost everywhere, we see

$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |f(x+k)| < \infty
$$

for almost all $x \in [0,1)$, i.e. for all $x \in [0,1) \setminus N$, with $N$ of measure zero.

It is now easy to see that $N' := \bigcup_{k \in \Bbb{Z}} N + k$ is also a null-set and that

$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |f(x+k)| < \infty
$$

holds for all $x \in \Bbb{R}\setminus N'$, hence for almost all $x$.

In particular, we get $|f(x+k)| \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ for almost all $x$. This is an even stronger statement then the one you are interested in.

Comment: I just noted that the second part of my argument was already posted here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137289/if-f-in-l1-mathbbr-then-sum-n-ge-1fxn-converges-for-a-e-x?lq=1.